# Android: implementing the linear magnifier in opengl es2.0

Tags: android, image-processing, opengl-es

In OpenGL 1.x , you can simply attach a texture to a quad of vertex to display an image, with using the linear magnifier parameter you can stretch or minimize the texture to a sidderent size in pixels without "seeing" it getting "pixelated".

In OpenGL es 2.0 there is another approach for rendering: using vertex and fragment shader.
so you simply render a texture (image) to the screen one needs to write he's own fragment shader for it - something like:

```
uniform sampler2D texture;
varying vec2 point; // coming from the vertex 

void main () {
   gl_fragColor(texture2D(texture, point));
}
```

the problem here is that the type of magnifier that takes place is a NEAREST kind. it takes the value of the closest pixel where the variable "point" is pointing.

I am in need of a linear magnifier.

My questiong here is: how do i implement such a thing in terms of code?
or am i doing something wrong from the begining?

there are no presets of fragment shaders to use for this type of at thing at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no presets in the fragment shader for this because it uses the same state as the fixed-function pipeline. A `sampler2D` uniform is the interface to a texture unit in the programmable pipeline, when you sample a texture bound to a texture unit in ES 2.0, the wrap state, filter mode, etc. are all taken from the texture object that is currently bound. You set these states the same way you would in ES 1.0. You are correct that you cannot change them in a fragment or vertex shader, but you should not need to, just bind a texture object with the appropriate state(s).

Desktop GL (3.3/4.0+) defines something called a sampler object, which decouples wrap mode and filter from the actual texture object. This is honestly the way it should have worked all along, having a texture object define both the data store and sampler state is wasteful. Unfortunately, this does not exist in OpenGL ES 2.0, so just remember that the filter state you mentioned is tied to texture objects and is not something you can set programmably within a shader.